# Integrating AWS lambda with a legacy SOAP API third party product

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, soap, lambda

I need to move the data from AWS Dynamodb to the third-party legacy product which uses SOAP API.
Used Eventbridge in between and we have transformed the data from JSON to XML using a lambda function.
As it is not 'REST API',I am not able to push the data directly into the legacy product.
So we need to use a lambda in between. How do I need to integrate the AWS lambda to that product using 'SOAP API'.
NOTE: Using python in lambda.